# Modify View of Shared Documents in SharePoint 2010/2013

Tags: permissions, column, view, user

So this is what is my requirement, I am trying to setup a page where different users can share their files (zip,doc.. etc), But i dont want one user to see other users upload document. So what i have done is that i have modified the view and used Created By and Modified By as [Me] , which is working for me so far.. But what i am not able to do is that I want one user to see all the users, e.g spadmin maybe or administrator or anyother user who should be allowed to see all the documents.

[image]

I hope this is clear.. if not i cannot explain in a different way..

Any help here will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another view in the page which shows all the documents and set the `Target Audience` of the that web part as admin only so that only he can see that view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to target this would be implement a **workflow** with the SharePoint Designer or a 3rd party tool that as soon as a file gets uploaded sets the corresponding permissions. This way only the users who shall view document x y z can actually access it.

The downside would be to have a very **granular permission** structure and another item (workflow) that could be a source of a future issue.